# How can I prevent Eclipse from stepping into Java library code

Tags: java, eclipse

How can I prevent Eclipse from stepping into Java library code when using Step Into?
What I am used to in other IDEs (like IntelliJ) is that with Step Into you enter the methods defined by yourself or third party libraries but not the methods of the Java framework itself. 
Eclipse does that and it really slows down debugging especially if you have calls to your own methods and ones defined in the Java framework in one line. You have to constantly switch between Step Over, Step Into or Step Return if you already stepped in.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can configure the Eclipse Java debugger to not step into those bits of code by configuring a ‘Step Filter’.

1. Go to Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Debug -> Step Filtering.
2. Check ‘Use Step Filters’.
3. Check the appropriate options on the screen. You can add parts that are relevant to your own codebase.
4. Click ‘Apply’.

More you can read about Eclipse Step Filter [here](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fdebug%2Fref-usestepfilters.htm)

You can even create a filter for your project Package or Java class as well.

Another good [link](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/help/html/step_filtering_preferences.htm)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For the People who wants to know same setting in Intellij Idea please go through below.

The reason intellij Idea do not step into java specific code is, by default Intellij Idea is enabled with below restriction. To add any other classes we can simply add it here. I added org.testng.* classes.

**File->Settings-> Build, Execution and Deployment -> Debugger -> stepping**

[image]